# Django / PostGreSQL: Create queryset grouped by 'date' when each row has a different timezone

Tags: django, postgresql, timezone, django-queryset

Let's say I have two models:

```
from django.db import model


class Company(model.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    timezone = models.TextField()

class Sale(models.Model):
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    company = models.ForeignKey('Company')
    time = models.DateTimeField()
```

I want to create a queryset grouped by date and company, where date refers to the calendar date of the sale at the timezone specified on the Company object.

This query:

```
result = Sale.objects.values(
    'company', 'time__date'
).aggregate(
    models.Sum('amount')
)
```

This returns the data in a format that works for me. However, the sales are grouped by UTC day. I want them grouped by the timezone on the Company objects.

What is the cleanest, quickest way to do this?

I know I could dump the entire set of values into Python, like this:

```
result = Sale.objects.values(
    'amount', 'company__timezone', 'time'
).order_by(
    'company_timezone'
)

for r in result:
    r.date = r.time.astimezone(pytz.timezone(r.company_timezone)).date()
```

and then groupby, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use the TruncDate function, and pass the timezone string as an argument.

```
from django.db.models.functions import TruncDate
from django.db.models import F
...

local_time_daily_sales = Sale.objects.annotate(
    date=TruncDate(tzinfo=F('company__timezone'))
).values(
    date
).annotate(Sum('amount'))
```